# How to keep Angular updated with Node.js data in real-time?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a Node.js backend and an Angular frontend. I want Angular to get notified every time a function is fired in the backend. Now, I do not want to use a timer for hitting the backend again and again. Instead, I want a constant subscription.
Can you suggest a way that does not involve sockets?

Comment: you can use an EventSource and server sent events..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason White mentioned, if you do not want to use web sockets, you could use EventSource. See

https://itnext.io/event-source-with-angular-c9f7f5369082 for the Angular client implementation

and

https://medium.com/conectric-networks/a-look-at-server-sent-events-54a77f8d6ff7 for an example of a node server implementation

However, you should keep in mind that EventSource does not work in IE or Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a publish-subscribe pattern.
I would suggest that you use Queues/Topics, like https://www.rabbitmq.com/.
Every time the function is fired in the backend, send a message to the queue/topic.
Make the angular app a subscriber of that queue/topic.

https://aws.amazon.com/pub-sub-messaging/